# What is the type for the closure |a: i32, b: i32| {a + b}?

Tags: rust, types, closures, rust-analyzer

I tried to type in what vscode was showing for my closure type definition, but it's wrong. What should I use instead?

My code:

```rust
let x = |a: i32, b: i32| {a + b};
```

rust-analyzer extension:

```rust
let x: impl Fn(i32,i32) -> i32 = |a: i32, b: i32| {a + b};
```

I want to manually define the types, so I usually will just type in what rust-analyzer provides me with, but in this situation it doesn't work. Since that is the improper way to use impl. What would I use instead?

Comment: You can't give it a name because every closure is its own distinct type. Rust analyzer is just helping you out by showing the closest thing to a nameable type.

Comment: Say I wanted to make something similar? Through some testing of my own I saw that `let x: fn(i32,i32) -> i32 = |a: i32, b: i32| {a + b};` doesn't raise issues. So that makes me wonder if there other ways of doing it.

Comment: @JaedonKLB That's not exactly the same thing, though. That casts the closure as a function pointer. The closure type is a ZST (zero-sized type) while the function pointer has pointer size and technically causes an indirect call (though that will likely be optimized away in simple cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure types don't have names in stable Rust, so you cannot actually name the type currently.

You will be able to name them when the [type_alias_impl_trait](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.html) feature is stabilized.  For example, on nightly you can do this, which aliases the closure type as `SumI32`:

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type SumI32 = impl Fn(i32, i32) -> i32;

fn create_sum_i32() -> SumI32 {
    |a, b| { a + b }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5333b3146f40f61c52f6dab7d9a5c98f))

Note that every closure has a distinct type, so this won't let you create arbitrary closures (even a completely identical one!) and treat it as a `SumI32`.

```
fn create_sum_i32_2() -> SumI32 {
    |a, b| { a + b }
}
```

```
error: concrete type differs from previous defining opaque type use
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     |a, b| { a + b }
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `{closure@src/lib.rs:6:5: 6:11}`, got `{closure@src/lib.rs:10:5: 10:11}`
   |
```